apt update unable to connect after kernel upgrade
Ubuntu 24.04 (upgraded from a long sequence of earlier releases). I recently updated from 6.8.0-31-generic kernel to 6.8.0-35-generic. After restarting the system, apt update could no longer connect to any repository; sometimes it times out, other times it seems to hang indefinitely. However, I can still ping the relevant URLs.
I have tried various ways to solve this problem, some of them following suggestions made in this forum: revert to the earlier 6.8.0-31-generic kernel; run apt update from a root-only console; reinstall apt; change to a different download server; run under a VPN; delete files from /var/lib/apt/lists and /var/lib/apt/lists/partial; disable IPv6; and possibly other approaches which I don't now recall. None of these has helped at all.
I understand that more info will be needed to find what has gone wrong, and I'll be happy to provide it when I know what is needed.

If you search this site you may find this is a problem that several have reported. Go back to the .31 for now.

I have tried using the 6.8.0-31-generic kernel instead of the newer 6.8.0-35-generic, but this does not fix the problem.

Please edit the question and put that info in. Also anything else you have done and missed in the question please add.

I've now done this. Thanks.
